# SFTP file transfer error - connecting to an unknown server and add its host key

Tags: sftp, ssh-keys, winscp, sql-job

I have created the batch to transfer the file using SSH keys, I checked the public and private key mapping on both the servers and it's working fine.

My Windows batch code using SFTP command is as follows:

```
open sftp://sftp_user@ssh_dest_server -privatekey="D:\directory_full_path\private_key.ppk" -rawsettings TryAgent=0 AuthKI=0 AuthGSSAPI=0

CD "/XYZ_Directory/folder1"
Put "\\full_directory_path\FILE1.zip"

exit
```

When I execute the batch manually it's executing fine without any issue, but when I execute batch from SQL Job (using different user) then it's shows below error:

```
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Continue connecting to an unknown server and add its host key to a cache?
The server's host key was not found in the cache. You have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is.
The server's RSA key details are:

    Algorithm:  ssh-rsa 2048
    SHA-256:    finger_print_key
    MD5:        zz:xx:yy:xx:yy:xx:yy:xx:yy:xx:yy:xx:yy:zz:zz:00

If you trust this host, 
    press Yes. To connect without adding host key to the cache, 
    press No. To abandon the connection press Cancel.

In scripting, you should use a -hostkey switch to configure the expected host key.
(Y)es, (N)o, C(a)ncel (10 s), (C)opy Key, (P)aste key: Cancel
Host key wasn't verified!
Host key fingerprint is ssh-rsa 2048 finger_print_key.

Authentication failed.
```

I already tried [`-hostkey`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey) WinSCP command but says *"unknown command"*. Suggestions are most welcome.

Something I want to do like this link "[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key)" through WinSCP command but inside my Windows batch automatically to verify the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify a host key in WinSCP script, add [`-hostkey` switch to the `open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey):

```
open sftp://sftp_user@ssh_dest_server -hostkey=... -privatekey="D:\directory_full_path\private_key.ppk" -rawsettings TryAgent=0 AuthKI=0 AuthGSSAPI=0
```

See [Verifying the host key ... in script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey) in WinSCP documentation. It covers everything you need to know. In particular, [where to get the host key value](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey).

Also note that WinSCP GUI can [generate a script template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) even with the `-hostkey` switch for you.

Also covered in [My script works fine when executed manually, but fails or hangs when run by Windows Scheduler, SSIS or other automation service. What am I doing wrong?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_scheduler)